# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined" when triggering cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that sends a notification to the receiver any time there's a new message written to the database associated with that user. I seem to keep getting errors.

I'm new with cloud functions and can't seem to fix this.

See the cloud function below

```js
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}')
.onWrite((snapshot,context) => {
    
    //get the userId of the person receiving the notification because we need to get their token
    const receiverId = context.params.userId;
    console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);
    
    //get the user id of the person who sent the message
    //const senderId = context.data.child('senderUid').val();
    const senderId = snapshot.data.child('senderUid').val();
    console.log("senderId: ", senderId);
    
    //get the message
    const message = snapshot.data.child('messageBody').val();
    console.log("message: ", message);
    
    //get the message id. We'll be sending this in the payload
    const messageId = context.params.messageId;
    //const messageId = event.params.messageId;
    console.log("messageId: ", messageId);
    
    //query the users node and get the name of the user who sent the message
    return admin.database().ref("/Renters/" + senderId).once('value').then(snap => {
        const senderName = snap.child("houseName").val();
        console.log("senderName: ", senderName);
        
        //get the token of the user receiving the message
        return admin.database().ref("/users/" + receiverId).once('value').then(snap => {
      //const token = snap.child("messaging_token").val();
      const token = event.data.child('receiverToken').val();
            console.log("token: ", token);
            
            //we have everything we need
            //Build the message payload and send the message
            console.log("Construction the notification message.");
            const payload = {
                data: {
                    data_type: "direct_message",
                    title: "New Message from " + senderName,
                    message: message,
                    message_id: messageId,
                }
            };
            
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                        .then(function(response) {
              console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
              //using this return statement to avoid error
              return response.successCount;
                          })
                          .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                          });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Any help on this would be much appreciated. I've different  ways to retrieve database values from the DatabaseSnapshot but non have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some test and and the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) there is no property `data` in `DataSnapshot` object. Due to this calling it will give `undefined` value. So if you call anything on this it will cause such errors.

It should help if you change `...snapshot.data.child('senderUid').val()...` to:

`...snapshot.child('senderUid').val()...`

Not sure why you added this `data` here, however it's not working even if you have child named "data" in the referenced path.